# Shredded Storage in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, shredded-storage

Is Shredded Storage part of SharePoint Server 2013 or available in Foundation edition as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seem like Shredded Storage is available in both on-premise editions, but is not available in SP Online.

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819267.aspx#bkmk_FeaturesOnPremise
- http://www.khamis.net/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=6c8a23d1-47ea-47e5-b56f-2bc57cb95b93&ID=96&Web=d64cd8b3-a3f4-40d8-8d93-6aa6dc82fcda

> Not available to SharePoint Online customers. Shredded storage is essentially the chunking of data—only differences are saved. That means if versioning is enabled and someone makes a change to a document, only changes “shreds” are added to the storage footprint of that document. Shredded storage improves I/O performance by reducing how much information retrieved by the web server from the content database. Shredded storage removes duplicate files, and improves data transmission speed.

Abailable in:

> Foundation - Yes; Standard - Yes; Enterprise - Yes.